# How to update network data in vis-network?

Tags: vis.js, visnetwork

My data comes from backend after I change some filters.

I want to be able to remove nodes that are no longer available and add new nodes without redrawing the whole network per the data from the backend.

My main goal is to have a seamless (no flickering) change on the graph while navigating on the filters.

Is there a good way to do that?  Or I need to loop through the data and do `remove()`, `update()`, `add()` manually for each node?